# SQL Server : "cannot insert the value NULL into column" but column is not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a strange problem with a script that is performing some inserts into a SQL Server table. It has been working fine until today but now it fails every time, however no changes have been made to the code.

It returns the error

> *Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'IRS VAT Prod_ Posting Group', table 'NAV_2009_Test.dbo.TEST Pxx 2011$Interface Invoice'; column does not allow nulls.*

As you can see, the `[IRS VAT Prod_ Posting Group]` column should be inserted with `VAT` - no column is null at all.

I tried changing the column to allow NULLS to see what would happen, but this made no difference.

This is my SQL statement :

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[TEST Pxx 2011$Interface Invoice] (
    [Entry Type],
    [Entry ID],
    [Reservation Contract],
    [Date],
    [Residential No_],
    [Gast Nr],
    Gastbezeichnung,
    [Moveware Customer No_],
    [Account No_],
    [Residential Cost Type],
    Description,
    Verrechnungsart,
    [Invoicing interval],
    Quantity,
    [Unit Price],
    Amount,
    [VAT Prod_ Posting Group],
    [Last Invoicing],
    [Next Invoicing],
    [Special Event],
    [Increase %],
    [Cost Unit],
    [Area Code],
    [From Date],
    [To Date],
    Address,
    [Post Code],
    City
)
VALUES
    (
        1,
        '590313',
        '1055',
        '2013-01-28',
        '',
        '1062',
        N'Jan Kling',
        '100127',
        '3030',
        '1',
        N'Sideboard ',
        '1',
        '1',
        '1',
        '17',
        '17',
        'VAT',
        '01-01-1753 00:00:00:000',
        '01-01-1753 00:00:00:000',
        '-',
        '0',
        '321',
        '',
        '2012-09-03',
        '2012-09-10',
        N'Zehnderweg 31',
        '4600',
        N'Olten'
);
```

As I said, no changes have been made to the code and so I am wondering if something could have gone awry on the server.

Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: Triggers? Is the table a view?

Comment: The column `IRS VAT Prod_ Posting Group` isn't mentioned at all in your insert query.  Is there a column with this name?  Does it have a default value?

Comment: @usr - No it is a table.

Comment: `[VAT Prod_ Posting Group]` is not the same as your error... `IRS VAT Prod_ Posting Group`

Comment: WAIT - you're right! I didn't notice the "IRS" part. Looks like somebody has been messing with my database without telling me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The column `IRS VAT Prod_ Posting Group` is not mentioned at all in your insert query.  It's likely that this column is `NOT NULL` and has no default value.