# Cannot insert the value NULL into column where using Sql Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Can you tell me how to avoid below mentioned exception ?

```
 INSERT INTO [Migrated].[dbo].[Cities] (Name, ZipCode)
     SELECT DISTINCT 
         a.City, a.ZipCode 
     FROM
         [Legacy].[dbo].[Ziplist] AS a 
     WHERE
         (a.City IS NOT NULL AND a.ZipCode IS NOT NULL);
```

Exception:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'IsDeleted', table 'Migrated.dbo.Cities'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: add IsDeleted to your insert statement, and give it a value.. OR add a default constraint to the field with a default value OR make it nullable

Comment: @JamieD77 Then how to fill it ? I need to put `false` on it.

Comment: `INSERT INTO [Migrated].[dbo].[Cities] (Name, ZipCode, IsDeleted) select  DISTINCT a.City,a.ZipCode, 0 from ...`  assuming it's a bit column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server : "cannot insert the value NULL into column" but column is not null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565842/sql-server-cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column-but-column-is-not-null)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Insert into ... values ( SELECT ... FROM ... )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @jamieD77 commented you are missing the `IsDeleted` column in your insert statement.

The error means that the column is marked as "NOT NULL" and therefore a value must be inserted when a new row is created.

So you either need to remove the NULL constraint from the table yourself or insert a value in the column.

```
 INSERT INTO [Migrated].[dbo].[Cities] (Name, ZipCode, IsDeleted)
 select  DISTINCT a.City,a.ZipCode,0 from [Legacy].[dbo].[Ziplist] as a where ( 
 a.City is not null and a.ZipCode is not null);
```

For a `bit` field which I would assume it is (but you should confirm!) the value `0` would be `false` and `1` would be `true`.  If the field is a different data type these values may have different meanings!!!

Comment: Can you tell me how to insert a value ? I need to insert `false` there.

Comment: if binary you would insert a 0, please confirm for example I may use a tinyint in certain cases to allow for more meanings than just deleted or not deleted.  There could be a status for mark for review prior to delete etc.

Comment: Yes,That is fine.Column type is `bit`.It's working.Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

What the error message says is that the `IsDeleted` column is declared `NOT NULL` *and* it does not have a default value.  In this case, you are probably inserting non-deleted records by default, so you might want to change column:

```
alter table cities alter column IsDeleted int not null default 0;
```

Alternatively, you can write the query to include the column:

```
INSERT INTO [Migrated].[dbo].[Cities] (Name, ZipCode, IsDeleted)
    select  DISTINCT zl.City, zl.ZipCode, 
    from [Legacy].[dbo].[Ziplist] zl
    where a.City is not null and a.ZipCode is not null;
```

These answers assume that `IsDeleted` is an integer with "0" for false.  If the values are stored differently, then the code needs to be modified appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the column to insert list and fixed value to select list.

```
INSERT INTO [Migrated].[dbo].[Cities] (Name, ZipCode, IsDeleted)
select  DISTINCT a.City,a.ZipCode, 0 IsDeleted --0 means false
  from [Legacy].[dbo].[Ziplist] as a 
    where (a.City is not null and a.ZipCode is not null);
```